# Multiple versions of perl6 using rakudobrew

Tags: raku

Is it possible to manage multiple versions of Perl 6 using [`rakudobrew`](https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew)?

I tried:

```
$ rakudobrew build moar
```

but this just overwrote my previous version, which was not what I intended to do. My previous version was `2017.04.3`, when I now type

```
$ perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2017.07-117-g5f68c7752 built on MoarVM version 2017.07-266-ged84a632
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

I am looking for something similar to `perlbrew install` and `perlbrew switch` which I use to switch between different version of Perl 5.

Comment: Just a heads up... [The `perlbrew` home page](https://perlbrew.pl/) calls it "an admin-free perl installation management tool". Aiui `perlbrew` generally works well for most Perl folk. While `rakudobrew` is described on the [rakudobrew home page](https://github.com/tadzik/rakudobrew) as "Perl 6 installation manager" it's also described as "quick and dirty ... may be broken on your system", and it's been that way for years. *core devs* love `rakudobrew` but that may be because core dev without it sucks so they're motivated to accept and fix any `rakudobrew` breakage they encounter. YMMV. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moar` is a backend. To get a specific Rakduo version, you have to specify it as well:

```
rakudobrew build moar 2017.07
rakudobrew build moar 2017.04.3
```

After doing this, you can choose which one to use:

```
rakudobrew switch moar-2017.04.3
```

If you are interested, run `rakudobrew list-available` to get a list of all Rakudo versions and backends that are available.

**A note to most users**: Unless you really have a need for the "bleeding edge" version of Rakudo, I'd recommend the relatively easier-to-install and "maintenance-free" [Rakudo Star distribution](https://rakudo.org/files). It is released about once every three months, so it's not that far behind the "bleeding edge" anyway.